# Accessing the HoloLens Accelerometer

Tags: windows, accelerometer, hololens

I'm trying to get the HoloLens's accelerometer data for the purpose of movement speed while in a car.

1. I tried using the Windows 'Devices' namespace to access their 'Sensors.Accelerometer' object, but that's inexplicably incompatible with the HoloLens ... a Windows Device.
2. I was able to cheat by calculating the speed of the camera object in Unity, but that only works relative to the headset wearer (when I test the app in the passenger seat of a car, I just the speed at which I move my head around).
3. Some time ago I'd found a Github repo from MS about HoloLens sensor streams, but I can no longer find it (Dear Future Me, clone EVERYTHING).

Does anyone know if there's another way I can get the accelerometer data? Either in C# or C++.

PS I have Research Mode and MS's demo app on my HoloLens and I've been analyzing that code for answers too. Didn't want anyone to think I show up here looking for a magic bullet!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use accelerations to calculate speed, you will run into problems because of error propagation and the lack of a reference point. Even if there is no direction change the integration of acceleration over the time will make values are useless after a short period of time. (s. [Getting displacement from accelerometer data with Core Motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449565/getting-displacement-from-accelerometer-data-with-core-motion) for example)

An alternative would be GPS but HoloLens doesn't a built in GPS sensor and pairing to phones over bluetooth was not possible in the past (maybe now). That said the only thing I can imagine is oopening a WiFi hotspot on a phone connect the HoloLens to it and write an app that will transfer GPS data via WiFi to the HoloLens app listening on the other end.

Comment: Thanks for responding! That thought about the phone has crossed my mind. I think I might just get a bluetooth OBD2 sensor, hook it to the car, and beam the telemetry data to the HoloLens.  I think it's kind of ridiculous that it's so difficult to get to the IMU sensors, especially now that MS has opened up the other raw sensor streams.