# Jenga from Apple Source Code / Motion Detection

Tags: iphone, motion-detection

Hello I was watching Apple WWDC 2010 and saw Steve playing jenga... Now I am die to see what is under the hood. Is there an code sample from Apple of that game? I was looking and can't find it...

May be someone can give me a link to it or something similar, perhaps tutorial?
I am dying to know how it works. Please help.

P.S: Here is a link ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORcu-c-qnjg ) to youtube, just so you know what I am talking about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenga was an actual application, available [on the app store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jenga-hd/id393106605?mt=8).  As such, you won't be able to find the source code for it.  However, you may be interested in the following:

[Apple gyroscope sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245733/apple-gyroscope-sample-code)

Which point you to Core Motion:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/CoreMotion_Reference.pdf

Here is another example with source code:

http://cs491f10.wordpress.com/2010/10/28/core-motion-gyroscope-example/

Comment: Is there anything that can simulate gyro? Jobs showed the game with Gyro (new iPhone 4) and without - which to work on 3GS. Am I corrent?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to CoreMotion, I will read on it tomorrow. Hopefully I can recreate similar behavior on 3GS