# mobile form hologram which protect from spamer

Tags: android, ios, mobile

What is **hologram** ?

How to implement this hologram in mobile web forms (instead of capcha) ?

As well, Anyone know any open source or showcase for this hologram, kindly refer.

Answer (score 2):

Definition from wiki, Hologram is **a three-dimensional image formed by the interference of light beams from a laser or other coherent light source.**

Generally holograms are used on product envelops to ensure authenticity of trademark/brand of the product. It's just a historical way used for many things like books, cloths etc, etc. But now, almost nobody is using them. Bar-code is more in fashion. It's really tough to find a product with hologram sticker on it in the market.

**Captcha** is used to authenticate human user & to avoid spam.

So, here I can't see any  "(instead of capcha)" thing for hologram.

Next thing, Even if you want to implement "Hologram" in your app, I don't think you can  implement real hologram effect on device.

One thing you can do is, you can detect device motion & virtually create hologram effect in your app.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135934/ios-gyroscope-api) might help you to implement `Core Motion` in iOS. Let me know if more info needed.

Comment: thanks for your information. actually this hologram is came to know ny know just 2 day ago only, i surfed lot of threads about holo gram, but i dont get any good article related to spam stopper.  i came across reference link like hologram stickers. but my expectation is mobile form spammer stop. so finally i decided and posted this thread.   client expecting hologram instead of capcha, if i am able to get good information, then i will ask to client.

Comment: Its good to know that I could Help. Feel free to accept/upvote the answer if it deserves the same :) @Bharanikumar