# What information about camera position can I deduce from two images and known real distances/angles?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, 3d

I have two images, and I'm trying to work out what I can about the camera location.

The images shows a lamp post in front of a window.

I can estimate the real window size, I know the real lamp post size. I also have the pixel distances for the window and the lamp post in both images. I know the real orientation of both objects (window sill parallel to ground, lamp post perpendicular).

The only thing that has changed is the zoom of the camera.

From this information, would I be able to deduce how far the camera is away from each object - or how far the objects are away from each other? And also the vector of the camera?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions like this is are a research field by itself. These problems are not trivial. Have a look [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT10/lect10.html) and the book by [Zisserman](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/)

Comment: what about posting the images so we can actualy see what exactly you are dealing with. Do you know the camera FOV angles and resolution?  also see [selection criteria for different projections](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32795205/2521214) so you know what to acount for and [Which is the best way to estimate measure of photographed things?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34085449/2521214) as you got 2 images and known objects you can compute the view locations from it and triangulate all the coresponding pixels to 3D locations

Comment: Also I hope the camera pixels are squares (aspect 1:1) otherwise you need to correct that first before anything else