# Is it possible to program this using the iPhone gyroscope?

Tags: iphone, 3d, gyroscope

I'm contemplating a casual 3D modeler app for phones. Here's the rough concept sketch: http://versuspad.com/image/3d-modeler.png

Would you think it is possible to program this, or do the Gyroscope and other approaches just not yield the desired data at all?

(I was not sure whether to post this here at Stackoverflow or at programmers.stackexchange.com, but choose the former for now, hope it's correct.)

Answer (score 2):

hmm... well quite innovative.. I must say.. you should have signed an NDA with all the viewers of your post..!!

coming back to the question, yes it is possible to read accelerometer values they way your app demands but the real thing will be the use that data to generate your desired application's output.

Comment: About the NDA -- a side task of mine is to find a brilliant programmer to implement it, so I want to get the idea out first to perhaps help attract a genius to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Absolute position is the double integral of acceleration.  Double integration amplifies noise and starting velocity errors so much, that any 3D model would get stretched way out of shape very quickly, and look nothing like the gestures in space.

Comment: Thanks, very useful feedback! Wonder how it would be possible to correct it via some additional camera input. Just today I stumbled upon markerless augmented reality... wow! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9HMn6bd-v8

Comment: Very interesting clip. After doing a lot of research in sensor based motion detection: the additional camera is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible with the iPhone. It would more use the Accelerometers than the Gyro, but do-able.

Coding it will be very difficult - but it is possible.

Just search around on Google and Stack Overflow and you might find a few useful ways how to use it. E.g. for [gyro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245733/apple-gyroscope-sample-code) and [accelerometer](http://www.technobuffalo.com/companies/apple/introduction-to-ios-development-playing-with-the-accelerometer/)

Comment: I don't think it's possible you need an external reference point to get precise motion detection