# How can I use gyrometer in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gyroscope

I want to get a device's rotation, altitude and slope.

Should I use gyrometer functions?

But I don't know how can I use them and which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple gyroscope sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245733/apple-gyroscope-sample-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [CoreMotion framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreMotion).