# Update rotational data from the gyroscope with respect to a predefined orientation?

Tags: ios, xcode, math, gyroscope, core-motion

Normally rotational data from the gyroscope y axis is updated with respect to vertical orientation of the phone. But if this orientation slightly changes as shown in the diagram, is there any method that i could take the component of y rotation to vertical axis(Vertical orientation position of the phone), ( This is possible for linear components by using Cosine angles sine angles) But what about rotation? Anyway i can we do this?
[image: Just a rough idea of the concept]

Comment: Could you put your question in other words, please? I am afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: By referring to the picture 1,  The phones rotation around y axis will be given when the phone is in vertical orientation, But what if the orientation of the phone changes as in the picture 2, Then in what way it updates rotation values? Is it still respect to vertical(y axis) direction or with an angle(axis through the phone in changed orientation position) If it's with change orientation position how can i convert it to a vertical orientation reading(with the phone in angle orientation)?

Comment: Short answer: Take a class on digital signal processing, then take another class on Kalman filters, and then take yet another class on Lie algebras. The long answer would require writing at least three college level texts.

Comment: @DavidHammen - Thank you for ur instruction! :/

Comment: @Sam, Im not sure exactly what youre looking for. If all you need is the angle of the phone to the vertical axis then take the gravity vector and find its angle to the vertical vector ...

Comment: @twerdster, Do you mean this? float gyro_x_ref=((rotate.x)*(rot.m11)+(rotate.y)*(rot.m12)+(rotate.z)*(rot.m13)); And also can i know exactly what i m calculating using this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my experience, gyroscope's values are mobile, meaning that the axis are updated as rotations intervene (that's true for Android, no reason not to be for iOS).

If you want to keep an eye on your 3 axis directions, you'll have to keep updated a rotation matrix :

[Direction Cosine Matrix IMU : Theory](http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf)

[Euler angles and DCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Relationship_to_other_representations)